# Hive Set up issue "SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory**"

Tags: hive

HAdoop single node cluster is working fine. HAdoop is working fine. JPS/Web interface of hadoop working fine.

I have done set up of hive.
When am entering into hive from hadoop its giving me below error :

**"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.SINGLETON from class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory**

Can someone help me in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you get the slf4j IllegalAccessError shown above, then you are using an older version of slf4j-api, e.g. 1.4.3, with a new version of a slf4j binding, e.g. 1.5.6. As mentioned in the [slf4j faq on IllegalAccessError](http://slf4j.org/faq.html#IllegalAccessError), this typically occurs when your Maven pom.ml file incorporates hibernate 3.3.0 which declares a dependency on slf4j-api version 1.4.2. If your pom.xml declares a dependency on an slf4j binding, say slf4j-log4j12 version 1.5.6, then you will get illegal access errors.

Also refer to the solution here: [IllegalAccessError slf4j](http://www.coderanch.com/t/430284/ORM/databases/java-lang-IllegalAccessError-access-field)